# Is there a simple way to do kafka reassignment for all the topics of the cluster during flex up

Tags: apache-kafka

We recently flexed up our clusters, and now I will have to assign the new broker id to all the existing topics of the cluster. Manually executing commands for generating reassignments and executing is taking very long time and effort.

Please suggest some way I can do this process as I am required to perform the same with around 1000+ topics.

I tried writing shell script to do it auto but that is not helping me so I am trying to explore any readily available solution which I can use.

Tried writing a script but its taking time I am looking for any readily available solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in Kafka is with `kafka-reassign-partitions` tool. You could try using Cruise Control, however, to otherwise "rebalance" a cluster in a more automatic way.